How to duplicate repositories to a new install?
My attempts to upgrade Focal to Jammy on one of my systems has failed miserably.  I'm falling back to doing it the hard way: doing a new Jammy install and moving everything over to it.  Maybe even going all the way to Noble (24.04).  It's going to be a lot of work given my setup, but I know how to do almost all of it.
The one thing I'm not sure about is how to get the list of added repositories, and implement it on the new system.  How do I do that?

Added repositories are located in the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ directory
They are ordinary text files. You can copy the files, or copy/paste the contents.
Keep in mind that non-Ubuntu repositories come and go. You would be wise to review each one before adding it to the new system.

Maybe the newer release of Ubuntu already has the version or feature you want.
Maybe the non-Ubuntu repo has not updated to support your new release yet. Or maybe it's abandoned. Such things happen.
Maybe you just don't use that software anymore.

For some users who want newer software, the normal 6-month releases of Ubuntu are just as stable as LTS, offer that desired newer software, and generally disrupt your workflow far less than going over the waterfall every two (or four) years.
For users who really want to keep LTS, best practice is to uninstall all non-Ubuntu software and disable non-Ubuntu sources before beginning the release-upgrade. Restore your system to as close to stock condition as possible for the greatest likelihood of success. After a successful release-upgrade, review and reinstall the non-Ubuntu sources and software.
